# 'Exiting' (ctrl+c) a process from console - Eclipse vs Intellij

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, kill-process

It seems that in Eclipse, if you want to send ctrl+c to a process you cant.
The terminate button on the console just kills the running process without running the shutdown hooks. I know that java itself doesnt allow sending a signal to another process.

However it seems that intellij idea does have a 'exit' button next to its 'stop' button which does allow shutdown hooks to run.

Can somebody tell me how intellij does this?

I need to send ctrl+c from my program to another java process too.

Comment: Didn't know about the 'exit' button. +1

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the 'Exit' button on IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.1 on mac os.

Answer (score 4):

Intellij use a native library to send a signal on Windows and the command kill on Unix.
[Here is a source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/11.0/com/intellij/execution/process/UnixProcessManager.java#UnixProcessManager.CLib)

Has you said you can't send a signal in Java. So you need to execute native code. 
[Look at the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835212/how-to-send-sigint-signal-from-java-to-an-external-process)

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that this happens only on Windows with Eclipse.
Also see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=38016

As far as just testing your hooks you can do it by calling System.exit() and then I suppose your users will not run the application using Eclipse so it's ok to count on it working for them.