# how send SIGINT signal from Java to an external process

Tags: java

I have created JAVA SWT based GUI which interacts with external C++ executable. My GUI invokes this c++ process using ProcessBuilder. Inside C++ process executable I have overloaded signal function (CTRL+c, CTRL+D). My question is how can i send CTRL+C into this external C++ process from Java SWT GUI? I already tried with 'kill SIGINT pid' which i got from link:[How to send SIGINT signal from Java to an external process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835212/how-to-send-sigint-signal-from-java-to-an-external-process), but sometimes the call doesnt work. Is there any alternate way i can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can send a SIGTERM with process.destroy ().

Comment: When does it not work? Which of the alternatives mentioned in the answers of the linked question have you tried?

Comment: I tried Runtime.getRuntime().exec((kill SIGINT pid) provided in the link from java code. Also I tried to send kill SIGINT pid from shell console too when C++ process is excuting and it seem to be not responding sometimes. Is the call kill SIGINT itself have some problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send CTRL+C to externl C++ process from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387173/send-ctrlc-to-externl-c-process-from-java)