# Sending a signal to a Process from Java 9

Tags: java, process, signals, java-9

I hear in java 9 they did a lot of work updating the Process API. Is there now a cleaner way to send a signal to a `Process` spawned by Java? The signals are used as a simple way to trigger actions in the process.

Before I had to use reflection to get a `pid` and then use `Runtime#exec` to send the `kill` command. I assume you still need to use `Runtime#exec` because signal may be OS dependent, but I'm curious if anyone knows a better way than this!

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);
...
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -SIGUSR1 " + p.getPid());
```

Comment: You could look at the doc: http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html The only obvious things I can see are `destroy` and `destroyForcibly`, but those were there already in Java 8.

Comment: @JornVernee yup that's where I saw `getPid` from. Just wondering if I missed anything!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send SIGINT signal from Java to an external process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835212/how-to-send-sigint-signal-from-java-to-an-external-process)

Comment: Unfortunately where Windows doesn't have signals this isn't something Java can expose cross-platform so your best bet is something like jnr-posix, though it won't work on Windows [\[1\]](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix/blob/c3ed9095db6eaf1c7ff65dc398c6cbaff7760e2f/src/main/java/jnr/posix/WindowsPOSIX.java#L151-L163).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> signal may be OS dependant

Yes, windows does not have signals in the same sense posix OSes do.

> but I'm curious if anyone knows a better way than this!

[jnr-posix](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix/blob/c3ed9095db6eaf1c7ff65dc398c6cbaff7760e2f/src/main/java/jnr/posix/POSIX.java#L82) provides thin wrappers around libc, including kill.